# Time Complexity for index and drop of first item in Data.Sequence

Tags: haskell, time-complexity

I was recently working on an implementation of [calculating moving average from a stream of input](https://gist.github.com/pellagic-puffbomb/9239cb57834789886f5c), using `Data.Sequence`. I figured I could get the whole operation to be O(n) by using a deque.

My first attempt was (in my opinion) a bit more straightforward to read, but not a true a deque. It looked like:

```
  let newsequence = (|>) sequence n
  ...
  let dropFrontTotal = fromIntegral (newtotal - index newsequence 0)
  let newsequence' = drop 1 newsequence. 
  ...
```

According to the [hackage docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html#g:11) for `Data.Sequence`, `index` should take *O(log(min(i,n-i)))* while `drop` should also take *O(log(min(i,n-i)))*.

**Here's my question:**

If I do `drop 1 someSequence`, doesn't this mean a time complexity of *O(log(min(1, (length someSequence))))*, which in this case means: *O(log(1))*?

If so, isn't *O(log(1))* *effectively* constant?

I had the same question for `index someSequence 0`: shouldn't that operation end up being *O(log(0))*?

Ultimately, I had enough doubts about my understanding that I resorted to using `Criterion` to benchmark the two implementations to prove that the `index/drop` version is slower (and the amount it's slower by grows with the input). The informal results on my machine can be seen at the linked gist.

I still don't really understand how to calculate time complexity for these operations, though, and I would appreciate any clarification anyone can provide.

Comment: Yes, those operations are constant time (in a model that ignores caching effects, GC costs, etc.) I don't understand what you are seeing in your benchmarks.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the comment. I actually ran the microbenchmark a numbe of times using both `nfIO` and `whnfIO` (because I couldn't figure out which one to use) and in each case the difference remained. One interesting thing, though, as the input size increased, the "outlying measurements" had a greater effect, to a point where it was like 70% when input size was 1 million.

Comment: I realized my second sentence will probably be misinterpreted. What I meant was: what do you see in your results, that you are trying to explain? Is it that `conduit` is 1% slower than `conduitV` for 10000 elements, but 2% slower for 100000 elements? That hardly seems to suggest, well, anything, but could easily be explained by extra GC work when there are more elements.

Comment: Well, it did appear that multiplying the input size by ten also multiplied the run-time difference by ten, which seemed to confirm the difference existed, which confused me because I thought they should be the same. (Not included are other inputs with different input sizes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest looks correct to me.

As a minor caveat remember that these are *amortized* complexity bounds, so a single operation could require more than constant time, but a long chain of operations will only require a constant times the number of the chain.

If you use criterion to benchmark and "reset" the state at every computation, you might see non-constant time costs, because the "reset" is preventing the amortization. It really depends on how you perform the test. If you start from a sequence an perform a long chain of operations on that, it should be OK. If you repeat many times a single operation using the same operands, then it could be not OK.

Further, I guess bounds such as `O(log(...))` should actually be read as `O(log(1 + ...))` -- you can't realistically have `O(log(1)) = O(0)` or, worse `O(log(0))= O(-inf)` as a complexity bound.

Comment: That may explain the difference, actually. I also realize now that I ran the benchmark in a "not-so-clean" state on my machine (things possibly happening in the background). I wonder if that could also color the results somehow? Strange that the difference was consistent across multiple runs. I appreciate the feedback, though, because I was doubting my math and it really seemed very simple to calculate in this case, so I was going a little crazy.